# Can my wrong derivation of the Gamma function be fixed?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, integral-equations

I found the following simple but wrong derivation of the Gamma function:

We start from the definition of the exponential function
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!} \\
\Rightarrow 1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k e^{-x}}{k!}
$$
Now we want to find a continuous version of this expression and argue that since $k!$ is not defined for real numbers we have to replace it with some function $f(k)$ so that the following expression stays true
$$
1 = \int_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k e^{-x}}{f(k)} dk
$$
So how do we solve for $f(k)$? We simply (and wrongly) exchange the variable of integration from $k \rightarrow x$ so we can move the unknown function f(k) to the left side and get
$$
f(k) = \int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^k e^{-x} dx
$$
This function is equal to $\Gamma[k+1]$. So we "calculated" very directly that the continuous version of the factorial is the $\Gamma$-function.

Of course this prove is wrong. But it seems so suggestive. So my question is, can one solve for $f(k)$ without any illegal tricks and derive the Gamma function in that way?